# Converting variable type (or workaround)

Tags: c++, types, fractions

The class below is supposed to represent a musical note. I want to be able to store the length of the note (e.g. 1/2 note, 1/4 note, 3/8 note, etc.) using only integers. However, I also want to be able to store the length using a floating point number for the rare case that I deal with notes of irregular lengths.

```
class note{
    string tone;
    int length_numerator;
    int length_denominator;
public:
    set_length(int numerator, int denominator){
        length_numerator=numerator;
        length_denominator=denominator;
    }
    set_length(double d){
        length_numerator=d; // unfortunately truncates everything past decimal point
        length_denominator=1;
    }
}
```

The reason it is important for me to be able to use integers rather than doubles to store the length is that in my past experience with floating point numbers, sometimes the values are unexpectedly inaccurate. For example, a number that is supposed to be 16 occasionally gets mysteriously stored as 16.0000000001 or 15.99999999999 (usually after enduring some operations) with floating point, and this could cause problems when testing for equality (because 16!=15.99999999999).

Is it possible to convert a variable from int to double (the variable, not just its value)? If not, then what else can I do to be able to store the note's length using either an integer or a double, depending on the what I need the type to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several possible solutions: the first is just to use double.  It's
true that extended computations may result in inaccurate results, but in
this case, your divisors are normally powers of 2, which will give exact
results (at least on all of the machines I've seen); you only risk
running into problems when dividing by some unusual value (which is the
case where you'll have to use double anyway).

You could also scale the results, e.g. representing the notes as 
multiples of, say 64th notes.  This will mean that most values will be
small integers, which are guaranteed exact in `double` (again, at least
in the usual representations).  A number that is supposed to be 16 does
**not** get stored as 16.000000001 or 15.99999999 (but a number that is
supposed to be .16 might get stored as .1600000001 or .1599999999).
Before the appearance of `long long`, decimal arithmetic classes often
used `double` as a 52 bit integral type, ensuring at each step that the
actual value was exactly an integer.  (Only division might cause a problem.)

Or you could use some sort of class representing rational numbers.
(Boost has one, for example, and I'm sure there are others.)  This would
allow any strange values (5th notes, anyone?) to remain exact; it could
also be advantageous for human readable output, e.g. you could test the
denominator, and then output something like "3 quarter notes", or the
like.  Even something like "a 3/4 note" would be more readable to a
musician than "a .75 note".

Answer (score 4):

If your only problem is comparing floats for equality, then I'd say to use floats, but read ["Comparing floating point numbers" / Bruce Dawson](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) first. It's not long, and it explains how to compare two floating numbers correctly (by checking the absolute and relative difference).

When you have more time, you should also look at ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to understand why 16 occasionally gets "mysteriously" stored as 16.0000000001 or 15.99999999999.

Attempts to use integers for rational numbers (or for fixed point arithmetic) are rarely as simple as they look.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to convert a variable from int to double, it is possible to convert a value from int to double. I'm not completely certain which you are asking for but maybe you are looking for a union

```
union DoubleOrInt
{
  double d;
  int i;
};

DoubleOrInt length_numerator;
DoubleOrInt length_denominator;
```

Then you can write

```
set_length(int numerator, int denominator){
    length_numerator.i=numerator;
    length_denominator.i=denominator;
}
set_length(double d){
    length_numerator.d=d;
    length_denominator.d=1.0;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that you absolutely must keep track of whether you are currently storing ints or doubles in your unions. Bad things will happen if you store an int and then try to access it as a double. Preferrably you would do this inside your class.

Comment: I would not go with the union - if you save a double into the union and then read the int, you'll get garbage - the double bit pattern reinterpreted as int (depending on architecture only 4 bytes).

Comment: Add a `bool` (or, for greater clarity, and `enum`) member that indicates which variant is currently active.  And don't allow anything outside the class to have direct access to the members; do it all through member functions (to avoid the possibility of accessing an inactive member).

Comment: `union`s are used occasionally in `C`, and very rarely in `C++`. Since we're talking about `C++`, I suggest you look into boost::variant (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) for a much safer solution to your problem.

Comment: @Gilad: I think boost::variant is overkill here.  It's useful if your types are not trivial, but when you're working with built-ins like int and double, unions are perfectly safe, as long as you use them right, which is really not that difficult to do.

Comment: @Benjamin: it's true that in this case boost variant doesn't have so much added value. There's also the overhead of using boost in the first place. It's just that "as long as you use them right" is something you have to take care to do everywhere in the code with unions.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for floating point variables. They are always rounded and the last digits may change valued depending on the operations you do. I suggest reading on floating points somewhere (e.g. http://floating-point-gui.de/) - especially about comparing fp values.

I normally subtract them, take the absolute value and compare this against an epsilon, e.g. if (abs(x-y)

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a `set_length(double d)`, my guess is that you actually need doubles. Note that the conversion from double to a fraction of integer is fragile and complexe, and will most probably not solve your equality problems (is 0.24999999 equal to 1/4 ?). It would be better for you to either choose to always use fractions, or always doubles. Then, just learn how to use them. I must say, for music, it make sense to have fractions as it is even how notes are being described.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would just use an enum. To turn something **into** a note would be pretty simple using this system also. Here's a way you could do it:

```
class Note {
public:
    enum Type {
        // In this case, 16 represents a whole note, but it could be larger
        // if demisemiquavers were used or something.
        Semiquaver = 1,
        Quaver = 2,
        Crotchet = 4,
        Minim = 8,
        Semibreve = 16
    };


    static float GetNoteLength(const Type &note) 
        { return static_cast<float>(note)/16.0f; }

    static float TieNotes(const Type &note1, const Type &note2)
        { return GetNoteLength(note1)+GetNoteLength(note2); }
};

int main()
{
    // Make a semiquaver
    Note::Type sq = Note::Semiquaver;
    // Make a quaver
    Note::Type q = Note::Quaver;
    // Dot it with the semiquaver from before
    float dottedQuaver = Note::TieNotes(sq, q);

    std::cout << "Semiquaver is equivalent to: " << Note::GetNoteLength(sq) << " beats\n";
    std::cout << "Dotted quaver is equivalent to: " << dottedQuaver << " beats\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Those 'Irregular' notes you speak of can be retrieved using `TieNotes`